# Is water a possible fuel for jet engines?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation, water, propulsion

Jet engines can run on almost any fuel, and the operating temperatures of modern jet engines' hottest sections are anywhere between 3000 and 3150 degrees F (1648 and 1732 degrees Celsius). Does that mean that a hydrogen on-demand system could work on modern jets?

Water is pumped and heated first by the exhaust section, then directed towards the hotter sections of the engine (when hot enough to not cause cooling and lower engine efficiency) where it's broken down into hydrogen and oxygen at a heat above 1472 degrees F (800 degrees Celsius), then those gases are pumped into the engine for combustion.

The advantages are that firstly, water is abundant and therefore cheap. Even sea water could be used because at those temperatures it's easy to design a system that would get rid of the impurities that would otherwise corrode critical engine parts.

Secondly, it would save on manufacturing costs given that non-heat critical parts in the exhaust section would not need to be made of sophisticated and expensive materials and alloys given the cooling effect of water.

Thirdly, the costs of the fuel weight would be reduced given that the energy density of hydrogen is twice that of fossil fuels, so less would need to be carried. And most importantly, the environment problem would be solved in aviation given that there would be little or no carbon dioxide emissions.

Comment: Do you know how conservation of energy works?

Comment: Breaking water down into hydrogen and oxygen costs as much energy as the combustion of hydrogen and oxygen to water releases.

Comment: You're trying to have your cake and eat it.  Not unlike a perpetual motion machine.

Comment: You have cross posted this on [Aviation SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/43891/is-water-a-possible-fuel-for-jet-engines) and [Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/82935/is-water-a-possible-fuel-for-jet-engines), which is not generally good behavior on a site like this.  And the answers have been quite emphatically "no, you can't use water".

Answer (score 3):

Energy has to come from somewhere--for example, to keep the hot parts of the engine from cooling down. If you start with water, split it, then recombine it, then you're back where you started. You can't get energy that way. It's not analogous to real jet fuel, where you start with a higher-energy chemical configuration (hydrocarbons + oxygen in the air) and end up with lower-energy (carbon dioxide + water vapor). In the process, energy is released, in the process creating heat and performing mechanical work, yet without violating Conservation of Energy.

So in this context water is not a "fuel".

Comment: Water is the by-product.  This is essentially asking "can I use the combustion products and waste heat to power a jet?"  And the answer is "No" unless you become a wizard who can reverse irreversible processes.

Comment: @JMac sorry even a reversible process doesn't produce net power...

Comment: I don't see how this violates conservation of energy: the water would absorb heat energy from the engine components and carry it away in the exhaust. The efficiency increases because waste heat is reduced... unless that high temperature is critical for engine operation somehow, of course.

Comment: @Asher - if you are using "some of the exhaust heat" to convert water to hydrogen and oxygen so the over all efficiency of the engine goes up, then no laws are violated. But that's not really "using water as fuel" in the way most people read the question.

Comment: @Floris true, and "propellant" is probably the more accurate term. Plus, even if engine efficiency goes up, vehicle efficiency probably comes down because you probably don't recover enough energy to offset the added carry cost for all the water you would need.

Comment: Injecting water into the later stages of a turbine is done routinely to help extract "the last bit of power" and reduce the output temperature. See [this](http://what-when-how.com/energy-engineering/water-augmented-gas-turbine-power-cycles-energy-engineering/)

Comment: @Floris With a kick to get it started it could run in place forever though.  Still not doable, and not practical even if it was.  Just trying to further illustrate that when you burn hydrogen you get water, so as a fuel it's pretty nonsense.  It would be like using the exhaust from your car and the heat to make your car move.  For starters, the system couldn't start itself, and beyond that, by using that heat and exhaust you would have to slow yourself back down as a consequence of getting the byproducts back.

Comment: @Floris Water injection has also been done in internal combustion engines.  I think this is basically a trick to cool the working fluid before ignition to increase the thermodynamic efficiency of the thing.

Comment: @tfb - yes, or at least to prevent knocking: the injected water prevents premature detonation which would mess up the timing (and thus efficiency) of the engine.

Comment: @Floris Yes, you're right.  And I've just realised that this is the same thing: if you can prevent knocking you can increase the compression ratio & thus efficiency.  I hadn't connected this before: thanks!